# tomcat url cannot be accessed from any other device

Tags: tomcat, web-development-server

I have created a webapp on tomcat 7. My registered domain name is www.example.com. I can access the webapp through localhost/xyz and http://www.example.com/xyz (the port is changed to 80) on my device. It can also be accessed through *myipaddress*/xyz from another device on my network.

I now, want the app to be accessed through http://www.example.com/xyz from any device (may not be on the same network).

I tried setting up port forwarding on my router. Didn't work out.

Comment: What is the response you are getting?

Comment: How and where have you configured the domain? Do you have a public ip address for your server?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with routers, there's no possibility to access a server from the network behind the same router with the domain-url. The request goes to the router, then to domain (example.com) and then it's sent back to the router - the router now detects a loop and declines the request.